# How to create a template variable like that of Angular 2?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, template-variables

I want to create a template variable in Xamarin Forms like the ones we can create in Angular.

For example like [this](https://www.xplatform.rocks/2016/01/07/angular2-quicky-local-template-variables/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use x:Name to name a view then refer to it elsewhere using x:Reference. Like the following:

```
<Slider x:Name="slider"
        Maximum="360" />

<Label BindingContext="{x:Reference slider}"
      Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='The angle is {0:F0} degrees'}" />
```

[Here is an article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/) showing this and other binding techniques.